# Email Format Expression, it should check after @ must be minimum 2 character before .com

Tags: regex, validation, email

I used this expression for email validation

```
/^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i
```

It's accepting aslo someone@h.com but I want user will need to input at least 2 character after @ and before .com to make it true

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
/^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i 
                          ^^^^
```

Have added the rule that there must be atleast two charcters after the `@`

https://regex101.com/

Comment: Still Accepting @h.com

Comment: Working Fine When added this / in starting